# Image I/O Error: "addImageFromSource:2179: image 0 of source is nil"

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, dng

I am trying to remove metadata from DNG images using the following function:

```
fileprivate func removeMetadataFromPhotoData(data: Data) -> NSMutableData? {
    
    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil) else {return nil}
    guard var type = CGImageSourceGetType(source) else {return nil}

    let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil) as Dictionary?

    let dngDict = imageProperties?[kCGImagePropertyDNGDictionary]
    var newDNGDict:NSMutableDictionary?

    if let dict = dngDict {
        newDNGDict = editDNGDict(originalDict: dict as! NSMutableDictionary)
    }

    let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
    let mutableData = NSMutableData(data: data)
    guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mutableData, type, count, nil) else {return nil}
    let properties: NSMutableDictionary = [String(kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary): kCFNull]

    if let dngDictionary = newDNGDict {
        properties[String(kCGImagePropertyDNGDictionary)] = dngDictionary
    }

    
    print("SOURCE: \(source)")
    
    for i in 0..<count {
        CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, i, properties as CFDictionary)
    }
    
    guard CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) else {return nil}
    
    return mutableData
}
```

the print statement prints the value of `source`, therefore, the source is not nil. However, when the next lines are executed I get the following errors:

> addImageFromSource:2179: image 0 of source is nil
>
> finalize:2470: image destination must have at least one image

I am doing the same process for other formats (JPG, PNG, TIFF, etc) and none of them have this issue. I would appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the CGImage code, but I did read that the `CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource` index parameter requests the index of the image. You give it the value of `0` which might cause your problem, as you previously use that index to obtain the properties at `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But they should be the same. Because I am getting the properties of the image and then making a new image from the same image. So the indices inside the source  are the same. I am not overwriting anything.

Comment: Another thing I notice (I've recreated your code and executed it with a custom asset from the xcassets), you have the `editDNGDict` function. What does that do? I do currently not get any error when executing my code...

Comment: I just set some of the values in the dictionary to "" . But that is not causing the problem. I even tried to copy the original metadata over and it still doesn't work. Would you tell me what version of Xcode and iOS you are using? Did you run it on a physical device?

Comment: Latest, not bèta. Disregard the working part, it works for png. It says xpc fails due to the dng type. I’m afraid so can’t help any further...